# General position - problem

Tags: measure-theory

In some homework I have the following:

Let A and B be two subsets of a universe $\mathcal{X}$ and that they are in general position

Find $\sigma(\{A\})$ and $\sigma(\{B\})$

I have no idea what general position means The book only says that A is not contained in B and that they are not disjoint which seems very weird

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We need more context. What is $\sigma$? Does this universe have any properties, or is it just a set?

Comment: It does not say anymore, I have added all @EthanBolker